# Composition of Trigonometric Functions (sin and cos)

Tags: trigonometry

If $h(x) = \cos \ x, f(x) = \sin \ x$, and $h = f \circ g$, what is $g$?

$\cos \ x = \sin \ (g(x))$

$g(x) = \sin^{-1} (\cos x)$

How would you proceed from here?

The answer choices are

a) $\frac{\pi}{2} - x$

b) $-x$

c) $\pi - x$

d) $\frac{3\pi}{2} + x$

e) $\frac{3\pi}{2} -x$

Comment: Can you see that $-sin(x) = -sin(x) * 1 +cos(x) *0$?And how will you continue from here,using basic trigonometric identities?

Comment: Oh shoot. I could have just used the complementary angle relationship between sin and cos angles when cos x = sin g(x). @TakaTiki But thanks anyway for your input. I found it refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You are lazy !

Compute:

1. $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$
2. $\sin(-x)$
3. $\sin(\pi+x)$
4. $\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2}+x)$
5. $\sin(\frac{3 \pi}{2}-x)$.

Then look were the result is $= \cos x$.

For 1., 3., 4. and 5. use the addition theorem.

Comment: I had already tried your method (and graphing them as well). What I am asking for is a purely algebraic way to solve this so that I can generalize it to other questions.